# How to set the width of the view displayed as a row in a NSTableView?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview, nsview, autoresize

I have a view-based `NSTableView`.

I have created a `NSView` to insert in this `NSTableView` as a row.
In the `xib` defining the `NSView`, the latter has a width set to `280`.

[image]

When I add my `NSView` to my `NSTableView`, the width of the former is changed to be equal to the width of the `NSTableView`.

[image]

Is there a nice way to prevent this behavior ?
I thought of including my `NSView` in another one, but I feel it is a bit hacky.

If possible, I would like a solution that only involves settings of the `NSTableView`. This `NSTableView` is indeed to be populated with many differents `NSView`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment to your previous question. You want to add your own views as subviews of NSTableCellViews. The NSTableCellView will be set to the width of the table, but your child view can be any width you like.

Comment: I added in `NSTableView` directly the views. For instance : I returned for the first `row` a `NSView` called `myView1`. Now, should I do `NSTableCellView * returnCellView = [[NSTableCellView alloc] init] ;
    [returnCellView setFrame:[myView1 frame]] ;
    [returnCellView addSubview:myView1] ;` ? It is not working.

Comment: I wonder why this `NSTableCellView`. By returning an `NSView` and adding constraints, it works. If there is a possibility to add any view, without setting up the constraints on it before, I would prefer. Thanks ;)

Comment: Finally, I did `NSTableCellView * returnCellView = [[NSTableCellView alloc] init] ; [returnCellView setFrame:[returnView frame]] ; [returnCellView addSubview:returnView] ; return returnCellView;`and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

this might be naive, but what happens if you **uncheck** *Autoresizes Subviews* in TableView's Attribute Inspector?

Comment: I did it and nothing happened. Finally, I did `NSTableCellView * returnCellView = [[NSTableCellView alloc] init] ;
    [returnCellView setFrame:[returnView frame]] ;
    [returnCellView addSubview:returnView] ;
    
    
    return returnCellView;`